# Fetching HTML or links from a website via Json/HtmlUnit

Tags: json, htmlunit

I have been trying to extract the html values from a page e.g. https://www.qwant.com/?q=cat&t=web but when I use jSoup or HtmlUnit I always get a basic page that doesn't compare to what is generated when I search via my normal browser.

My codes in general work on other websites but could someone explain to me why when I visit the above with code that I don't get the same results? I am trying to fetch all the url values on the page. Is it to do with javascript?

```
  WebClient wb = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52);      
  wb.getPage(url);
  wb.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(25000);
  System.out.println(wb.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage().getWebResponse().getContentAsString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Some website just won't allow you to parse them headlessly (for obvious reasons). As I tried to `curl` the Qwant cat result page, the result was a blank page.

But you want to give a try at switching from Firefox to Chrome as your browser : [It is *not* possible to detect and block Chrome headless](https://intoli.com/blog/not-possible-to-block-chrome-headless/)

Comment: Do you get any log output? Try to add wb.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false); directly after the WebClient creation.

Comment: Hi Martin, With jSoup and HTMLUnit I have tried Chrome, IE and Firefox and get the same result. In addition I tried Jaunt and got the same result. I will print the error tomorrow when I'm in front of the code.